Sum values in one column for the first time a value shows up in another column only
I have an Excel worksheet that has a column for a job name and another column for Total for that job.



Job
Cost
Contact




123
$500
John


567
$150
Mark


123
$500
Mary


ABC
$750
Erin



My goal is to create a total for all the jobs, but only include one for each job. In other words Job 123 shows up twice, but I only want it to be counted once.  The total for all of these should be $1400 for the example.

Show your work so far.

Use UNIQUE function to generate new Job and Cost columns with just the unique values, and SUM just that?

@Michael Letendre Can you provide another table with your expected output?

The formula below assumes you only want to count the first instance if there are multiple instances of the same job (as per your title). However, if you want to count all instances if the multiple instances have different costs, then this will need modification.
If you have 365 you can use:
=LET(
    a, Jobs,
    h, CHOOSECOLS(Jobs[#Headers], 1, 2),
    j, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(a, 1)),
    t, BYROW(
        j,
        LAMBDA(arr, XLOOKUP(arr, CHOOSECOLS(a, 1), CHOOSECOLS(a, 2)))
    ),
    VSTACK(h, HSTACK(VSTACK(j, "Total"), VSTACK(t, SUM(t))))
)

Note that I use a Table (named Jobs) and structured references, but you can change this to regular references if you prefer.


Assumptions:
Cost for a Job will be the same for each Contact on that Job.
Your table starts in A1.
Try:
=LET(
    _hdg, A1:B1,
    _unq, UNIQUE(A2:B5, FALSE),
    _vals, CHOOSECOLS(_unq, 2),
    _tot, SUM(_vals),
    VSTACK(_hdg, _unq, HSTACK("Total", _tot)) 
)



Note that your version will double count jobs if the Costs are not the same for multiple instances.  In his Title, he only wants to count the first instance, but the body of the question is not as clear.

@Ron Rosenfeld Right. I've added that assumption to my answer.

If the Jobs in column A are stored as text, you could simply use:
=SUM(UNIQUE(A2:B5))
else =SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(A2:B5),,1))

All as one function:
=SUM(INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(UNIQUE(A2:A5),A2:A5,0)))

Much longer formula that may be easier to understand:
=LET(jobList,A2:A5,costList,B2:B5,jobs,UNIQUE(jobList),costs,INDEX(costList,MATCH(jobs,jobList,0)),SUM(costs))

The LET() function allows you to store data as variables and then reference the data later using the variable's name. The parameters are a collection of name,value pairs with the last entry being the output. I'll explain that formula and it will help you understand the first formula, too.

jobList,A2:A5 just stores the input list. You don't need to define this, really, but it makes the formula easier to change later since you only need to change the reference range in one place instead of in multiple.
costList,B2:B5 just stores another piece of the input. You don't need to define this, either, and it's only referenced once so it's even less helpful than jobList but it does make the formula easier to understand.
jobs,UNIQUE(jobList) extracts just the unique jobs from the list.
costs,INDEX(costList,MATCH(jobs,jobList,0)) looks up the first instance of each of those unique jobs in the job list. MATCH() returns only the first instance and, with 0 as the last parameter, it looks for an exact match no matter the list order. Then, the INDEX() part will find the corresponding value from the cost list.
SUM(costs) adds up all those costs it pulled out in the last part.

You can transform the big LET() function into the smaller - but harder to follow - single function by substituting each variable step-by-step:
=LET(jobList,A2:A5,costList,B2:B5,jobs,UNIQUE(jobList),costs,INDEX(costList,MATCH(jobs,jobList,0)),SUM(costs))
=LET(costList,B2:B5,jobs,UNIQUE(A2:A5),costs,INDEX(costList,MATCH(jobs,A2:A5,0)),SUM(costs))
=LET(jobs,UNIQUE(A2:A5),costs,INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(jobs,A2:A5,0)),SUM(costs))
=LET(costs,INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(UNIQUE(A2:A5),A2:A5,0)),SUM(costs))
=LET(SUM(INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(UNIQUE(A2:A5),A2:A5,0))))
=SUM(INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(UNIQUE(A2:A5),A2:A5,0)))

